# Запуск программ

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Возможно ли сделать так что-бы операционная система не требовала установки .NET Framework и других компонентов для запуска программы а брала их из файлов программы? Например .NET Framework 4.6.2 устанавливается около или более 5 минут не на слабом компьютере.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
//using System.IO;
//using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
//using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну в той или иной форме .NET должен быть на машине. Вы думаете, он просто так устанавливается 5 минут? Если бы можно было влёгкую сэкономить, Майкрософт бы сэкономила.

Comment: @VlaD Что делать?

Comment: А почему вариант с установкой не подходит? Вроде бы на современных системах везде .NET стоит и так.

Comment: @VlaD Там веб-установщик который надо на 2 минуты. Я ещё качал через Nuget System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, это в другой системе потребуется только .NET Framework? Я сейчас добавлю список моих подключений к проекту. То что комментарий я добавил сам.

Comment: Вы можете использовать инсталлятор, который так или иначе может выяснить какую версию .NET нужно устанавливать, НО вы не сможете подключить только 2-3 или несколько файлов из .NET так как они все очень плотно завязаны и используются один в другом. Поэтому это и называется framework - ОСНОВА для разработок, это не просто так несколько файлов где есть классы или функционал, который можно модульно-пофайлово подгружать.

Comment: @DanielProtopov Хорошо, но зачем мне инсталлятор если у меня программа сама инсталлятор? И я наверно бы установил framework из самой программы но она не запускается. Вы можете сказать какого framework мне хватит для работы с моими компонентами? Что можно сделать? И программа сама пишет какая версия ей нужна для запуска, точнее наверно та которая указана в настройках проекта.

Comment: Тебе нужен инсталлятор написаный на нативном языке, который будет включать в себя дистрибутив Framework'а и твою программу на .NET.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников Можно пример?Название. Какая версия .NET мне подойдёт?

Comment: Можешь изучить WiX. В частности такие вещи умеет WiX Bundle: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/

Comment: @АртёмОконечников Спасибо

Comment: Это как установка клиента. Это нужно устанавливать. Например SAP тоже надо устанавливать чтобы он работал и достаточно много. 1c Тоже требует установки. Почеум Ваша программа не должна требовать установки компонентов? Пишите на ассемблере. Тогда ничего не придется ставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

До недавнего времени такой возможности не было, и приходилось использовать инсталляторы.

Сейчас же у нас есть .NET Core и его self-contained applications.
На эту тему уже написано много статей, в том числе и на русском.

Вот, например:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/311520/

Comment: .NET Core еще сырой и там никогда не будет WPF

Comment: @vitidev ну, да, он еще сыроват, но его активно допиливают, и уже в этом году он, вероятно, будет готов к коммерческому использованию. Что же касается WPF, уже разрабатываются неплохие сторонние библиотеки для разработки кроссплатформенного UI на .NET, а System.Xaml планируют выпустить в рамках .NET Standard 2.0 в первом квартале этого года. Так что, хоть пока всё и не идеально, активно движемся в правильную сторону )

Comment: @Fynivx Насчет System.Xaml в рамках .NET Standard 2.0, можно ссылку на источник?

Comment: @vitidev не могу найти пост, в котором читал именно про System.Xaml, но вот статься, в которой написано, что .NET Standard 2.0 будет поддерживать UWP. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/

Comment: Core позиционируется как кроссплатформенный. Да и UWP хуже WPF. И ладно UI (там хоть Avalonia есть), но отсутствие поддержки System.Transactions мешает.